# Wrong conversion of unix timestamp to human time

Tags: php

I'm trying to display how much time a user is connected.

but when i convert the unix timestamp to human time the `H` displays the current hour, instead of the timestamp hour.

```
echo date("H:i:s", "320");
```

result: 19:05:20

desired result: 00:05:20

Comment: It's showing it in your current timezone, which is 5 hours behind UTC.

Comment: Use `DateInterval` for periods of time, `date()` is for dates and times.

Comment: For completeness, unix timestamps are defined as "the number of seconds since `1970/01/01 00:00:00 UTC`" so basically you've fed in `1970/01/01 00:05:20 UTC` and then `date()` formatted it according to the configured default timezone, which would seem to be UTC-5. For a simple duration [time without date] you should avoid types/functions with date components, eg: DateInterval as Barmar suggested, or just doing a bit of math.

Answer (score -1):

this setting depends on the set server time reading, you can set this up with the .htaccess file by adding

```
php_value date.timezone 'Europe/Warsaw'
```

my zone is 'Europe/Warsaw' as in the example

here you have all of it List of Supported Timezones https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

then from that date time you set the counter

```
echo date("H:i:s", "-3280");
```

Comment: only answers are not a good method of answering, put a little more effort and give the details for your answer, read here more about how to give a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer